# Unity DI Container RegisterType method breaking changes from v5.8.x to v5.9.x

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core, unity-container, mediatr

I was using **Unity DI Container v5.8.4** on my .NET Core 2.1 project and I needed to register `Mediator` object and I was using the configuration suggested [here](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/tree/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.Unity).

Now I have updated to **v5.9.4** and I have an error about `RegisterType` method arguments:

> Cannot convert from 'Unity.Lifetime.LifetimeManager' to 'Unity.Injection.InjectionMember'

This is my actual code:

```cs
public static IUnityContainer RegisterMediator(this IUnityContainer container, LifetimeManager lifetimeManager)
{
    return container.RegisterType<IMediator, Mediator>(lifetimeManager)
        .RegisterInstance<ServiceFactory>(type =>
        {
            var enumerableType = type
                .GetInterfaces()
                .Concat(new[] { type })
                .FirstOrDefault(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

            return enumerableType != null
                ? container.ResolveAll(enumerableType.GetGenericArguments()[0])
                : container.IsRegistered(type)
                    ? container.Resolve(type)
                    : null;
        });
}
```

What have I to do to update the registration code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They have changed the signature of the `RegisterType` in this [PR](https://github.com/unitycontainer/abstractions/issues/90) and it is now taking a `ITypeLifetimeManager` instead of a `LifetimeManager`.

The `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` is now implementing the `ITypeLifetimeManager` interface so you just need to update the `lifetimeManager` parameter in your `RegisterMediator` method:

```
public static IUnityContainer RegisterMediator(this IUnityContainer container, 
                                                    ITypeLifetimeManager lifetimeManager)
{
    return container.RegisterType<IMediator, Mediator>(lifetimeManager)
        ...
}
```